# Sorting HTML table not working properly

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a HTML table:

```
<table id="myTable2" border="1">
 <tr>
    <th onclick="sortTable(0)"> Code </th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(1)"> Name </th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(2)"> Total Input </th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(3)"> Total Output </th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(4)"> Total Retour </th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(5)"> Stock Left </th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(6)"> Safety Stock </th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(7)"> Stock Status </th>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to add sort function to it by using this script:

```
<script>
    function sortTable(n) {
      var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
      table = document.getElementById("myTable2");
      switching = true;
      //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
      dir = "asc"; 
      /*Make a loop that will continue until
      no switching has been done:*/
      while (switching) {
        //start by saying: no switching is done:
        switching = false;
        rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
        /*Loop through all table rows (except the
        first, which contains table headers):*/
        for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
          //start by saying there should be no switching:
          shouldSwitch = false;
          /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
          one from current row and one from the next:*/
          x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
          y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
          /*check if the two rows should switch place,
          based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
          if (dir == "asc") {
            if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
              //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
              shouldSwitch= true;
              break;
            }
          } else if (dir == "desc") {
            if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
              //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
              shouldSwitch= true;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        if (shouldSwitch) {
          /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
          and mark that a switch has been done:*/
          rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
          switching = true;
          //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
          switchcount ++;      
        } else {
          /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
          set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
          if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
            dir = "desc";
            switching = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

For the first two column (Code and Name), the sort function works perfectly, both ascending and descending option. But rest of the table, the function isn't working properly. Several rows move up or down but it's not in sort order. Would anybody please tell me how I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: I suspect it's because the first two columns are strings whilst the remainder are numbers but you are sorting them as though they are strings which means that 101 will come before 25. Can you give a sample of the data?

Comment: there are loads of plugins out there which will do this kind of thing for you very reliably. Are you writing your own as a learning exercise, or for some other reason?

Comment: @RobAnthony You're right, I just realized that. Code, Name, and Stock Status are strings. Others are numbers. That script sort all of them as strings. Would you please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: @ADyson I don't know anything about plugin. I'm trying to build a simple inventory system using php and mysql.

Comment: "I don't know anything about plugin". That's what google is for... As for the fact it's an inventory system, how is that relevant to your question, do you think? Table sorting is table sorting, it really doesn't matter much what the data is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your function to:

```
<script>
    function sortTable(n,isNum) {
      var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
      table = document.getElementById("myTable2");
      switching = true;
      //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
      dir = "asc"; 
      /*Make a loop that will continue until
      no switching has been done:*/
      while (switching) {
        //start by saying: no switching is done:
        switching = false;
        rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
        /*Loop through all table rows (except the
        first, which contains table headers):*/
        for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
          //start by saying there should be no switching:
          shouldSwitch = false;
          /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
          one from current row and one from the next:*/
          x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n].innerHTML;
          y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n].innerHTML;
          if (isNum) {
          /* Convert to float */
          x = parseFloat(x);
          y = parseFloat(y); 
          }
          else
           {
           /* change to lowercase */
           x = x.toLowerCase();
           y = y.toLowerCase();
           }
          /*check if the two rows should switch place,
          based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
          shouldSwitch = ((dir =="asc") && (x>y)) || ((dir =="desc" && (x<y))
        if (shouldSwitch) {
          /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
          and mark that a switch has been done:*/
          rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
          switching = true;
          //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
          switchcount ++;      
        } else {
          /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
          set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
          if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
            dir = "desc";
            switching = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Change your HTML to:

```
<table id="myTable2" border="1">
 <tr>
    <th onclick="sortTable(0, 0)"> Code </th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(1, 0)"> Name </th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(2, 1)"> Total Input </th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(3, 1)"> Total Output </th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(4, 1)"> Total Retour </th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(5, 1)"> Stock Left </th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(6, 1)"> Safety Stock </th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(7, 1)"> Stock Status </th>
 </tr>
</table>
```